# Вопрос о тестировании класса

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, mocking, nunit

Добрый день. Предположим у меня есть примерно такой класс:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(Iprovider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public Foo[] LoadFoo(string url)
    {                
        return _provider.GetData(url, MyConverter);
    }

    private Foo[] FooConverter(string)
    {
        // тут некая большая логика конвертации
    }

    private readonly IProvider _provider;
}
```

в качестве IProvider передается такой класс:

```
public class Provider: IProvider 
{
    public T GetData<T>(string url, Func<string, T> converter) 
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {                
            string data = client.DownloadString(url);
            return converter(data);               
        }
    }
}
```

Я хотел бы покрыть класс MyClass тестами, но не очень понимаю, как это сделать. Дело в том, что вся его логика сосредоточена в методе `GetData` класса `Provider` и в методе `FooConverter`. Предположим в юнит тесте я подменю Provider на некий ProviderMOck, например такой:

```
public class ProviderMock: IProvider 
{
    public T GetData<T>(string url, Func<string, T> converter) 
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

Но тут возникает вопрос: что тогда тестировать? Ведь получится, что при таком моке даже не используется метод `FooConverter`. Написать что-то типа

```
[Test] 
public void Test()
{
    var mock = new ProviderMock();
    var myclass = new MyClass(mock);
    var foo = myclass.LoadFoo(String.Empty);

    Assert.NotNull(foo);
}
```

Но это по сути тест ради теста. А вот основная логика (конвертация с помощью `FooConverter`) так и остаётся не протестированной. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Я бы задал вопрос - связан ли `FooConverter` с назначением всего класса? Не нарушен ли принцип единственности ответственности? По мне так это кандидат на отдельный класс с отдельной ответственностью, и протестирован также должен быть отдельно.

Comment: У любого теста логика проста: подаем на вход заранее известные данные, получаем назад результат, сверяем результат с заранее известным результатом. Эта вся суть любых тестов. Даже проверка на ошибки делается подобным же образом: подаем в тесте данные, которые вызывают заранее известный тип исключения, проверяем, что исключение было выброшено, и то, что исключение имеет заранее предопределенный тип.

Answer (score 1):

Вы смешали ответственности классов (см. [принцип единой ответственности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)). Класс провайдер должен заниматься только поставкой данных. Он инкапсулирует логику "добычи" этих данных (в вашем примере -- это http-запрос). Но он не должен заниматься конвертацией данных.

Потому что, скорее всего, в ковертации данных у вас присутствует некоторая бизнес-логика.

Поэтому провайдер должен выглядеть так:

```
public class Provider: IProvider 
{
    public T GetData<T>(string url) 
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {                
            return client.DownloadString(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Однако тут проблема: `DownloadString()` возвращает `string`, а нам нужен `T`. Тут уже зависит от того, какие вы данные получаете, но это, скорее всего, json или xml. Тогда нужно десериализовать ответ и возвращать его объектное представление:

```
public class Provider: IProvider 
{
    public T GetData<T>(string url) 
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {                
            string data = client.DownloadString(url);
            return Deserialize<T>(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь к `MyClass`:

```
public Foo[] LoadFoo(string url)
{                
    var data = _provider.GetData<SomeObject[]>(url, MyConverter);
    return FooConverter(data);
}

private Foo[] FooConverter(SomeObject[] data)
{
    // тут некая большая логика конвертации
}
```

, где `SomeObject` -- это объект того типа, который возвращает провайдер.

И вот теперь можно легко и правильно написать тест:

```
[Test] 
public void Test()
{
    string url = string.Empty;

    // воспользуемся библиотекой Moq
    var provider = new Mock<IProviderMock>();
    var data = new[] { new SomeObject() { Field1 = 1 } };
    provider.Setup(p => p.GetData<SomeObject>(url)).Return(data);

    var myclass = new MyClass(provider);
    var foo = myclass.LoadFoo(url);

    Assert.NotNull(foo);
    // проверка должна строиться на основе того,
    // что возвращает мок, и вашей логики конвертации
    Assert.AreEqual(data.Length, foo.Length);
    Assert.AreEqual(data[0].Field1 * 2, foo[0].Field1);
}
```